# After Login the get route not worked in vue js Component in laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, authentication, vue-component

i want to load my provinces list in vue.js component , my code is worked , but when i  login , show nothing in my list , here is my code

**in my vuejs component :**

```
    <template>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group required col-6">
            <label for="province_id">Province</label>
            <div class="col-12">
                <select class="form-control" name="province_id[]" id="province_id" multiple v-model="province" style="height: 200px"
                        @change="getAllCities()">

                    <option v-for="province in provinces" :value="province.id">{{province.name}}</option>

                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group required col-6" v-if="cities.length> 0">
            <label for="city_id">City</label>
            <div class="col-12">
                <select  class="form-control"  multiple="" name="city_id" id="city_id" style="height: 200px">
                    <option v-for="city in cities" :value="city.id">{{city.name}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>

        </div>


    </div>
</template>


<script>

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                province: 'Select Province',
                cities: [],
                provinces: [],
                flag: false,
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            axios.get('/api/provinces').then(res => {
                // console.log(res);
                this.provinces = res.data.provinces;
            }).catch(err => {
                //  console.log (err)
            })
        },
        methods: {
            getAllCities: function () {

                console.log()

                axios.get('/api/cities/(' + this.province + ')').then(res => {

                    console.log(res);

                    this.cities = res.data.cities
                }).catch(err => {
                    //  console.log (err)
                })
            },
        }
    }

</script>
```

**in Register Controller :**

```
public function getAllProvinces()
{
    $provinces=Province::all();

    $response=['provinces'=>$provinces];
    return response()->json($response,200);
}
```

my code work before login and show all provinces in my db , but after login there is nothin in my select , please help about that .

Comment: Are there any errors showing in the console? In your browser's developer tools, look at the network log. Do you see the `GET` to `/api/provinces` being sent? If so, what status and data does it return? Does the URI look right? Can you copy and paste it into a new tab and see the expected data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because RegisterController uses guest middleware, you just don't pass the middleware when logged in, also it isn't good to me to use any method not related to the controller. Create new ProvinceController and define your method there it'll work

```
// this is RegisterController constructor
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');
}
```

But if you somehow want to use your method exactly in the RegisterController then use except() method in constructor:

```
// add except
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest')->except(['getAllProvinces']);
}
```

Comment: thank you for answer , i create ne cotroller and it's work

Comment: Good) you are welcome) You chose the best solution for your issue, adding except() method would help you too, but as I mentioned it's not right one